# Php include using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, module, load

I'm creating a web page that is built using "modules", in other words the page is put together using other php files.

On one side of my page there is a div container with some links next to it, this div container will be used to hold certain information. The information is held within separate php files that I wont to be able to load into the div container with the links I mentioned earlier.

How would I go about doing this with ajax?

Note: I load the php files with include("");

Comment: are you using a javascript library like jQuery/prototype/mootools?

Comment: I'm not using any, for the site I'm building, I only require ajax for querying the database and reloading information on the page. So I thought it would be best to just use my own code instead of a library, am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AJAX shouldn't replace your PHP `include`s unless there is a particular reason you want to do this (e.g. page load performance is poor and you want to load some sections asynchronously to the rest of the page).

I would carry on using PHP includes, but if you then want to dynamically update those page sections after the first load, you can use [Prototype's Ajax Updater](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater).

Bear in mind that this is not like a server-side include; the parts of the page you update, if they are PHP scripts, will not have access to variables that were set in the rest of the page; you'll need to supply these as GET or POST data with the asynchronous request.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX - here we're talking about involvement of Javascript. So i'll use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) here

index.php:

```
<?php

// your main file
echo '<div id="module">Please wait while loading...</div>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javsacript">/* <![CDATA[ */';
echo '$(window).ready(function(){
         $("#module").load("module.php");
      });';
echo '/* ]]> */</script>';

?>
```

module.php:

```
<?php

echo 'Today is '.gmdate('l');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

for what its worth this is how you would update a div with an id of items using [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater):

```
new Ajax.Updater('items', '/your_remote_script.php');
```